# MySQL: Show all rows with same column value one after the other with the column value appearing only once

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns:

```
ResourceId | Reason
```

I have 4 rows with values as follows

```
2884 | irrelevant
3441 | irrelevant
2884 | incorrect
1234 | incorrect
```

I want the data to appear something like this:-

```
2884 | irrelevant
     | incorrect
3441 | irrelevant
1234 | incorrect
```

i.e. I want all the rows with similar ResourceId to appear together as a group but I only want to display the ResourceId for the first row. How can I write a query for this?

Comment: It's not a MySQL task to put makeup on the output. The data even is incorrect without a key. MySQL is made to work with data, not to make data look nice like in a managers report. You could use `GROUP_CONCAT()` but still, MySQL is not Microsoft Excel.

Comment: Its better if you do this in your application code